# Android Picasso - How to obtain stats on cache hits and downloads

Tags: android, picasso

I'm currently using Picasso 2.0.1(also tried 1.0.2 before) and obtaining bitmaps from pictures on the web.

All is working great, I've seen improvements in loading the images ... at least it seems faster.

My question is, how can I get statistics from the activities done by PICASSO? I wanted to know if the picture was obtained from the cache or downloaded ...

I'm trying to obtain information with com.squareup.picasso.StatsSnapshot, however it doesn't seem to get updated... or I'm not using it correctly.

```
Picasso pi = Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
Bitmap bitmap = pi.load(url.toString()).get();
Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"Cache hits:" + pi.getSnapshot().cacheHits + " Cache misses:" + pi.getSnapshot().cacheMisses);
```

adding a log before and / or after the load call always return the same result

> Cache hits:0 Cache misses:0

What am I doing wrong or how can I obtain this information?

Thanks in advance!

Marc

Comment: Do not call `getSnapshot()` multiple times. Just call it once in your method and use that instance instead. It seems you are using `get()` which is a synchronous background loading, I dont think that affects cache stats. Try using `load(url).into(imageView)` and then get a snapshot... see this thread https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/215

Answer (score 5):

To get the colored triangle that David Hewitt is describing, you actually have to use setIndicatorsEnabled like so

```
Picasso.with(mContext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
```

You can get stats in your logs for Picasso by using setLoggingEnabled like so

```
Picasso.with(mContext).setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

You can search the log with a "Picasso" filter and see where Picasso gets the image and how long it takes. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

According to the website here:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

You can do `setDebugging(true)` and it will place coloured triangles in the corner or each image that will indicate whether they were loaded from the web, the disk or memory. I can't find any specific reference to the functions you were using on the website, but this may meet your needs instead.

Comment: I actually had added pi.setDebugging(true) even without properly knowing its impact to see if the statssnapshot got updated.

I don't see the "colored ribbon" as they call it on the bitmaps I get... maybe since I'm not performing the .into(imageView1), but putting the bitmap after some processing the bitmap doesn't get the overlay?

Either way this wouldn't help me to know in the application if the image was a download or not ... Surely there has to be a way? what's the use of StatsSnapshot if not for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call this from the onStop() or onPause of your Activity or Fragment

```
StatsSnapshot picassoStats = Picasso.with(context).getSnapshot();
Log.d("Picasso stats ", picasspStats.toString());
```

then from the Android logcat select verbose and filter by Picasso.

You will get a log something like the following:

```
Picasso stats: [main] StatsSnapshot{maxSize=76695844, size=75737296, cacheHits=656, cacheMisses=1091, downloadCount=8, totalDownloadSize=213376, averageDownloadSize=26672, totalOriginalBitmapSize=437547196, totalTransformedBitmapSize=609434304, averageOriginalBitmapSize=527801, averageTransformedBitmapSize=735143, originalBitmapCount=829, transformedBitmapCount=826, timeStamp=1484426664382}
```

Answer (score -1):

'get()' is synchronous and skips the cache. Use one of the 'load()' methods to harness Picasso's full powers.